# Add New Button in Admin Panel

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, redirect

I am learning Plugin Development in WordPress. I have an Add New button in one of my Admin panel page like below.

[image]

I would like to redirect to `http://127.0.0.1/wordpressplugin/wp-admin/admin.php?page=newAddress` when click on it.

I wrote below code for this

```
echo '<div class="wrap"><h1 class="wp-heading-inline">Addresses</h1>
        <a href="'.admin_url("admin.php?page=newAddress").'" class="page-title-action">Add New</a>';
```

But this code is not redirecting to that link. What is the solution ?

How did it done here ?

[image]

Thanks.

(Sorry for my poor English.)

Comment: Can you make your slug "newAddress" to "newaddress" In your admin_url code? Also, did you create the new address page? If not then it would be a different approach.

Comment: Thanks @PradiptaSarkar. Actually `newAddress.php` is file name where I would like to redirect. Thanks.

Comment: How did you create those page? Did you used add_menu_page concept?

Comment: Thanks @PradiptaSarkar. Yes, I used `add_menu_page()` function. Could you please say how did the button used in `Users` list (See second image) ? Thanks.

Comment: What is your slug name? You need to pass a query string with your page slug. And within your call back code you can check for the query parameter and conditionally include that file. As an example your main slug used in add_menu_page is myslug. Then your new address url look like this admin_url("admin.php?page=myslug&add=new").

Comment: Thanks @PradiptaSarkar for your reply. I solved the issue using this `'<a href="'.admin_url("admin.php?page=newAddress").'" class="page-title-action">Add New</a>'`. But I have curiosity about your reply. Why do you use `add=new` ? What is usage of it ? Thanks.